# Why wont pip work outside of PyCharm

Tags: python, powershell, cmd, pip, pycharm

I think I may have screwed myself.

I had pip working in my venv in PyCharm fine

but whenever I try to accsses pip from the powershell or cmd line, it doesn't recognize the command. I double checked the path variables and everything, and now further discouraged as the GUI platform I was working with  wont open in the venv.

What are my options here? I need to get pip working in the powershell, it says it's there when I upgrade it, but says its missing when I try to use it, which is unbelievably frustrating. tried also uninstalling pip from the venv but that didn't help anything either. Any help is greatly appreciated.

when I try to install pip normally, i get this

> PS C:\Users\lerug\Downloads> py .\get-pip.py
>   Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\users\lerug\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages
>   PS C:\Users\lerug\Downloads>

Comment: Have you tried activating the venv from powershell first?

Comment: Does "python.exe -m pip list" work? It sounds like the <python_src>\Scripts directory is not in the path.  What are you doing exactly that's failing?

Comment: no the above doesnt work, im trying to use pip to install appJar and it refuses to accept the source i have pointed to python. how would I activate the venv from the powershell? by venv i just mean the terminal in PyCharm

Comment: I would do this inside of PyCharm but appJar doesn't seem to work inside of it, im just worried now that I wont be able to do python stuff from my powershell or cmd line again, unless I factory reset

Comment: From the command line (not powershell) path to your virtualenv. Then try typing `Scripts\python.exe -m pip install appJar`. What happens?

Comment: says that the requirement is already satisfied with this address:

Requirement already satisfied: appJar in c:\users\lerug\desktop\python\counter-cutter\venv\lib\site-packages

Comment: Okay, so I'm assuming that's the path to your virtualenv and therefore `appJar` is already installed. If you use the interpreter from the command line (`Scripts\python.exe`) and enter `import appJar` does it work?

Comment: Have you tried specifying the _pip_ version?(I.e. `pip2 install matplotlib`)

Comment: @HFBrowning  yes that works

Comment: @AndrewNagyeb yeah originally I tried pip3 and pip2

Comment: Okay. So basically it sounds like things are pretty much working as expected. PyCharm is a nice IDE because when you set up a project you can configure your local interpreter (`python.exe` file) and it will remember. Command line will default to your environmental settings unless you tell it explicitly the path of the pip/python you want - which will always be in the Scripts folder of your virtualenv. You DON'T want to change your environmental settings to point to these because things get all screwed up that way - it negates the whole point of keeping things isolated. Does this make sense?

Comment: yes that does, ill go delete all those environment variables I created now, thank you so much, this was really panicking me

Comment: You're very welcome. I'll reformat it as an answer for posterity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PyCharm is a nice IDE because when you set up a project you can configure your local interpreter (`python.exe`) and it will remember. The Windows command prompt defaults to your environmental settings unless you tell it explicitly the path of the pip/python you want - which will always be in the Scripts folder of your virtualenv.

So for instance, to use the virtualenv version of pip you can path to your environment and type `Scripts\python -m pip install <package>` (noting that I have had trouble using `Scripts\pip install <package>` directly before; but given that the former has always worked, I haven't bothered to figure out why). Similarly, you can use the virtualenv python interpreter on the command line simply by typing `Scripts\python`.

You DON'T want to change your environmental settings to point to your virtualenv .exe because things can get pretty messed up that way. It also negates the point of keeping your python environments isolated.

As an aside - usually people interact with a virtualenv by "activating" it. This is optional and just puts everything relative to the Scripts folder (so you don't have to keep typing `Scripts\` in front). The other benefit is that you can start pathing around to other directories and the command line will remember (while it is activated) that you want to use *those* particular versions of pip and python. If you're using the command line you can activate with `Scripts\activate`. If you're using PowerShell you'll need to use `Scripts\activate.ps1`.